# Sub Field of File Field

Tags: custom-field, metabox

Is it possible to add sub text field alongside with file field (for PDF upload) with "meta box" plugin or even custom code?
taking into consideration that the file field is multiple ex:

File #1: [FILEUPLOAD] [FILENAME]

File #2: [FILEUPLOAD] [FILENAME]

[#ADD MORE#]

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: may i see example of meta box example !?

Comment: I'm sure you can.